# Hyperlink (a href) with a pound sign at the end doesn't do anything in Firefox

Tags: html

I have a link that is somewhat like this:

```
<a href="------.html#video">Text</a>
```

It works fine in IE but not in Firefox. In Firefox it shows the new URL on the address bar but doesn't update or change anything in terms of content.
Somehow the "#" is causing Firefox to ignore updating the page. I tried using Javascript "window.location" and "window.location.href" and all sorts of other things but it still doesn't work. 
Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `<a name="video" ...` on your page?

Comment: This isn't enough info.  Post your code.  Changing fragments is expected to navigate within the page and/or allow JavaScript to take special actions.  Most likely you have IE-specific JavaScript watching the fragment.

Comment: Is the page name `------.html` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make the link go to a different script page which will then redirect the browser back to the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Press F5 / Ctrl+F5 to force Firefox to relaod the page. Firefox does not reload the page but only jumps to the html anker `video` that is defined in the link ...